# Using custom nginx.conf with Chef Cookbook

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook

I'm using http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx to install Nginx on Vagrant

I'd like for Nginx to start with my configuration file `/home/vagrant/nginx/nginx.conf`, however it seems to insist on using `etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

The relevant section of my Vagrantfile is:

```
chef.add_recipe "ohai"
chef.add_recipe "runit"
chef.add_recipe "nginx"

chef.json = {
    :nginx => {
        :install_method => "source",
        :source => {
            :version => "1.4.1",
            :conf_path => "#{VAGRANT_HOME_DIRECTORY}/nginx/nginx.conf",
        }
    }
}
```

What's going on here??

Comment: I'd also be cool with installing it from the package. In the end, I really just want it to run using my nginx.conf...

Answer (score 5):

I install and configure nginx with my requirements as below. This is my recipe for nginx installation and configuration:

```
include_recipe "apt"

apt_repository 'nginx' do
  uri          'http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/'
  distribution node['lsb']['codename']
  components   ['nginx']
  key          'http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key'
  deb_src      true
end

apt_package 'nginx' do
  action :install
end

file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
   action :delete
end

cookbook_file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" do
   source "nginx.conf"
   action :create
end

service "nginx" do
   action :start
end
```

Explanation:

1. Configure the nginx repo under `sources.list`. This needs the [apt](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apt) cookbook which provides `apt_repository` LWRP,
2. Delete the existing `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and copy a pre-defined one using `cookbook_file`. I have already configured `nginx.conf` as per my requirements and saved it under `files` directory of the cookbook.

Bottom line, I do not install nginx using the nginx cookbook; instead, I install it as a package and then configure it as per my needs.

Comment: The delete action is redundant, since the cookbook_file  block will overwrite whatever is present anyway.    By omitting the delete action, you can at least see a diff in the output to warn you that something just changed.